# Exibir vários Custom post type na index

Tags: php, css, wordpress, style

Eu tenho um template Wordpress com Múltiplos post type, e eu consigo fazer a consulta e exibir todos os Custom post type na index.

Meus Custom post type são uma área reservada apenas para Filmes, Séries e Blog, só que na minha index eu só mostro os Filmes e as Séries porque eles aparecem igual.

Ex. de como aparece na minha index:

[image: Ex]

Como aparece meus post na área do blog:

[image: Ex2]

Mas minha duvida e a seguinte, como eu consigo mostra todos esses post na minha index, tipo, eu uso um modelo diferente na área do blog, mostro apenas uma imagem e uma descrição, já na minha área de filmes e series eu mostro varias informações.

Como eu faço para distinguir os post para exibir todos na index e sem ficar bugado?

```
<?php $args = array('post_type'=>array('filmes', 'series')); query_posts($args); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php   if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'home');
    $imgsrc = $imgsrc[0];
} elseif ($postimages = get_children("post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=0")) {
    foreach($postimages as $postimage) {
        $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($postimage->ID, 'home');
        $imgsrc = $imgsrc[0];
    }
    } elseif (preg_match('/
        <img [^>]*src=["|\']([^"|\']+)/i', get_the_content(), $match) != FALSE) {
        $imgsrc = $match[1];
    } else {
        $imgsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/no-imagen.png';
    } ?>
```

Sei que para exibir os post da área do blog basta adicionar nos array depois do post_type, mas quando aparece fica bugado a parte de exibição.

Ex.:

[image: Ex3]

Comment: Você pode fazer um `if` usando a resposta da função `get_post_type`

Comment: Você poderia me dar um exemplo de como começar, eu não sou bom em PHP, só manjo em html e css, PHP eu só desenrolo pelos tutoriais.

Comment: [**Exemplo**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/#comment-1687). Dentro desse `if`, bastaria montar o *layout* de acordo com o *post type*.

Comment: usei e deu certo, no entanto, vou ter que modificar todo o template, pois só para mostra o postagem de um filme eu faço a consulta de aproximadamente 10 taxonomias diferentes para exibir os valores, usei a função 'echo' para mostrar, existe algum outro método para exibir sem ter que adaptar o código, digo, apenas colar o código puro sem ter que fazer as consultas e depois exibir assim '.$value.'

Comment: tipo, para fazer a consulta da qualidade por exemplo, eu utilizo essa função "<?php if($values = get_post_custom_values("item_quality")) { ?><?php echo $values[0]; ?><?php } ?>" como eu faço para colocar ela dentro do if sem ter que adaptar para '.$value.'

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a sugestão do usuário [@Valdeir Psr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99718/valdeir-psr)

```
<?php if ( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'filmes' ) {
    echo 'postagens no custom post type filmes';
} elseif ( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'series' ) {
    echo 'postagens no custom post type series';
} elseif ( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'blog' ) {
    echo 'postagens no custom post type blog';
}
?>
```